# Updating Magento to 2.2.2: errors on block attributes

Tags: layout, magento2.2, upgrade

I'm trying to update Magento 2.1.8 to 2.2.2. After the update I get errors about block attributes on layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `type` and `src_type` (and maybe others) from elements of your layout files.

For example, I had to remove them from thesr layouts:

```
app/design/frontend/themevendor/themename/magento_theme/layout/default.xml
app/design/frontend/mytheme/base/magento_theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove/change some of the attributes (error will tell you what is needed to be removed/changed). Xml validation has been updated with 2.2.x version.